# How to install movie-trailer npm package without these errors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules, npm-package

How do you install the movie-trailer npm package without getting these errors:

```
$ npm I movie-trailer
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/movie-tralier - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'movie-tralier@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\CCS LAPTOP HYD\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-19T21_09_44_170Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong arguments and/or a package that cannot be found.

Comment: bro, Then what should I do?

Comment: Try this: ```npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org```, and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled word `movie-trailer` in that command, try this `npm i movie-trailer`